# Windows 8 store , Json Deserialize

Tags: c#, json, windows-8, windows-store

im trying to deserialize a Json that i get from a webservice Like so:

```
                 Uri urlJson = new Uri("http://optimizingconcepts.com/staging/cartuxa/system/json_request.php?lang=pt");
             var client = new HttpClient();
             HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(urlJson);
             var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

the Json i get is this:http://paste2.org/MpYJd8kk

I then do this to get the JsonObject:

```
 JsonObject root = Windows.Data.Json.JsonValue.Parse(jsonString).GetObject();
```

What i want to know, is the correct way of saving each object from json to a list
so the objects from "home" would be in a List, the objects from "artigos" would go to a List and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Json.Net](http://json.codeplex.com/), it can be done as follows

```
Uri urlJson = new Uri("http://optimizingconcepts.com/staging/cartuxa/system/json_request.php?lang=pt");

var client = new HttpClient();
var json = await client.GetStringAsync(urlJson);
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cartuxa.RootObject>(json);
```

I used `http://json2csharp.com/` to generate below classes.

```
public class Cartuxa
{
    public class Home
    {
        public object id { get; set; }
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Artigo
    {
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string submenu { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string subtitle { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<object> media { get; set; }
    }

    public class Year
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string file { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public List<Year> year { get; set; }
    }

    public class Vinho
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string submenu { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Product> product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Year2
    {
        public string year { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string file { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product2
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
        public List<Year2> year { get; set; }
    }

    public class Azeite
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string submenu { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public List<Product2> product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Agente
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string continent_id { get; set; }
        public string country_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
    }

    public class Continente
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Pais
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string continent_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
    }

    public class Contacto
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string menu_id { get; set; }
        public string submenu_id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string phone { get; set; }
        public string fax { get; set; }
        public string longitude { get; set; }
        public string latitude { get; set; }
    }

    public class Premio
    {
        public string image { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

    public class Noticia
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string menu { get; set; }
        public string date_created { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        public string subtitle { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public List<object> media { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public List<Home> home { get; set; }
        public List<Artigo> artigos { get; set; }
        public List<Vinho> vinhos { get; set; }
        public List<Azeite> azeites { get; set; }
        public List<Agente> agentes { get; set; }
        public List<Continente> continentes { get; set; }
        public List<Pais> paises { get; set; }
        public List<Contacto> contactos { get; set; }
        public List<Premio> premios { get; set; }
        public List<Noticia> noticias { get; set; }
    }
}
```